# Find the perimeter of the section determined in the cube, by a plane guided by 3 points determined below

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

A cube $ABCD A_1 B_1 C_1 D_1$ is given, with edge $a$. On the edge $C_!D_1$we take a point $L$, with $C_1L=\dfrac{3a}{4}$; on the edge $A_1B_1$ we take point $M$, with $A_1M=\dfrac{a}{2}$; on the edge $BB_1$, point $N$ is taken, with $B_1N=\dfrac{a}{4}$.
Calculate the perimeter of the section determined in the cube, by a plane guided by points $L$, $M$ and $N$.

The answer I got is correct but I considered that the triangles $MB_1N$ and $LC_!E$ are similar but I was unable to demonstrate it. Would it be possible to demonstrate this similarity or is there another way to resolve it?

[image]

$\triangle MNB1:MN^2=(\frac{a}{4})^2+(\frac{a}{2})^2 \implies \boxed{MN = \frac{a\sqrt5}{4}}\\ MO \perp D_1C_1 (O \in D_1C_1)\implies \triangle MLO: LM^2 = a^2+(\frac{a}{4})^2 \implies \boxed{LM=\frac{a\sqrt{17}}{4}}\\ \triangle MB_1N \sim \triangle LC_1E :\\ C1E.\frac{a}{2}=\frac{a}{4}.\frac{3a}{4} \therefore C_1E = \frac{3a}{8}\\ \triangle LC_1E: LE^2 = (\frac{3a}{4})^2+(\frac{3a}{8})^2 \therefore \boxed{LE =\frac{3a\sqrt5}{8} }\\ P \perp C_1E:(P \in C_1E) \implies \triangle NPE: NE^2 = a^2+(\frac{3a}{8}-\frac{a}{4})^2 \therefore \boxed{NE=\frac{a\sqrt65}{8}}\\ 2p =\frac{a\sqrt5}{4} +\frac{3a\sqrt5}{8}+\frac{a\sqrt{17}}{4}+\frac{a\sqrt{65}}{8}=\\ \frac{5a\sqrt5}{8}+\frac{a\sqrt{17}}{4}+\frac{a\sqrt{65}}{8}=\boxed{\frac{a}{8}(5\sqrt5+2\sqrt{17}+\sqrt{65})}$

Comment: Isn't it by obviousness? EG $LE\parallel MN$, because these are both the (say) xy cross section of the plane.

Comment: In solid geometry two lines on two parallel plane are said to be parallel. If these two lines are in one plane intersecting the two parallel planes, then they are parallel in the inter-sector plane.

Comment: @sirous Thank's for help

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If you have to show that triangles $LC_1E$ and $MB_1N$ are similar, project $LN$ on the plane having triangle $LC_1E$, call it $M'N'$, now in this plane, as I explained in comment we have:

$MN||LE\Rightarrow LE||M'N'$

which deduces two triangle are similar.